# Performance discrepancy: obj.__setitem__(x,y) vs. obj[x] = y?

Tags: python, performance

I was writing up a simple `dict` subclass with attribute access, and I stumbled across something that seemed strange when I was optimizing. I had originally written the `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods as simple aliases to `self[key]` etc, but then I thought it should be faster to call `self.__getitem__` and `self.__setitem__` directly, since they would presumably be called under the hood by the `[key]` notation. Out of curiosity, I timed both implementations, and discovered some surprises.

Below are the two implementations: not much going on here, as you can see.

```
# brackets
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self[key]
    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        self[key] = val

# methods
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.__getitem__(key)
    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        self.__setitem__(key, val)
```

Intuitively, I expected the second implementation to be slightly faster, since it presumably skips the step of going from the bracket notation into a function call. However, that's not exactly what my `timeit` results showed.

```
>>> methods = '''\
... class AttrDict(dict):
...     def __getattr__(self, key):
...         return self.__getitem__(key)
...     def __setattr__(self, key, val):
...         self.__setitem__(key, val)
... o = AttrDict()
... o.att = 1
... '''
>>> brackets = '''\
... class AttrDict(dict):
...     def __getattr__(self, key):
...         return self[key]
...     def __setattr__(self, key, val):
...         self[key] = val
...
... o = AttrDict()
... o.att = 1
... '''
>>> getting = 'foo = o.att'
>>> setting = 'o.att = 1'
```

The code above is all just setup. Here are the tests:

```
>>> for op in (getting, setting):
...     print('GET' if op == getting else 'SET')
...     for setup in (brackets, methods):
...             s = 'Brackets:' if setup == brackets else 'Methods:'
...             print(s, min(timeit.repeat(op, setup, number=1000000, repeat=20)))
...
GET
Brackets: 1.109725879526195
Methods: 1.050940903987339
SET
Brackets: 0.44571820606051915
Methods: 0.7166479863124096
>>>
```

As you can see, using `self.__getitem__` is very slightly *faster* than `self[key]`, but `self.__setitem__` is significantly *slower* than `self[key] = val`. This seems very odd--I know function call overhead can be large, but if that were the issue **I'd expect to see the bracket notation faster in both cases**, which is not happening here.

---

I looked into it a little further; here are the `dis` results:

```
>>> exec(brackets)
>>> dis.dis(AttrDict.__getattr__)
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (key)
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR
              7 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(AttrDict.__setattr__)
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                2 (val)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (key)
              9 STORE_SUBSCR
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
>>> exec(methods)
>>> dis.dis(AttrDict.__getattr__)
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (__getitem__)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (key)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(AttrDict.__setattr__)
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (__setitem__)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (key)
              9 LOAD_FAST                2 (val)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             15 POP_TOP
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

The only thing I can think of is that maybe the `POP_TOP` instruction has significant overhead compared to the rest of the calls, but can it really be **that** much? It's the only thing that stands out here... Can anyone see what's going on to make `__setitem__` so much slower than its bracket-cousin, relative to `__getitem__`?

Potentially relevant info:

**CPython 3.3.2 32-bit** on **win32**

Comment: Is the speed-up seen by the get pair reproducible? I suspect that `__setitem__` is doing more work than `__getitem__`, so that the slow down is more noticeable. That is, `__getitem__` may be fast enough that any apparent speed up is due to experimental error.

Comment: @chepner Yes. I'm using a 20x-repeated `timeit` call with a million iterations per run, and the results have been the same (relative to each other) every time I've run the timing loop (five or six times).

Comment: Another possible factor that could cloud the issue: your `setattr` test *only* sets a value, while your `getattr` test must retrieve the value *and* bind it to a name. As a result, retrieving a value appears to be nearly 2x slower than setting a value. How do the timings look when you change `getting` to simply `o.att`?

Comment: @chepner That's actually what I had at first! I was afraid that I was getting bad comparisons because `setting` needed another item (the constant `1`), so I added the variable binding. It does slow `getting` down a little, but only *very* little, and all the relative results remained the same.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm that's interesting. If I run a pared-down version of your stuff:

```
setup="""
def getbrack(a, b):
    return a[b]

def getitem(a, b):
    return a.__getitem__(b)

def setbrack(a, b, c):
    a[b] = c

def setitem(a, b, c):
    return a.__setitem__(b, c)

a = {2: 3}
"""
```

`setitem` and `getitem` are both slower than their corresponding `setbrack` and `getbrack`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("getbrack(a, 2)", setup, number=10000000)
1.1424450874328613
>>> timeit.timeit("getitem(a, 2)", setup, number=10000000)
1.5957350730895996
>>> timeit.timeit("setbrack(a, 2, 3)", setup, number=10000000)
1.4236340522766113
>>> timeit.timeit("setitem(a, 2, 3)", setup, number=10000000)
2.402789831161499
```

However, if I run exactly your test, then I get your same results - `GET 'Brackets'` is slower than `GET 'Methods'`.

This means it has something to do with the classes you're using and not bracket vs. setitem per se.

---

Now, if I modify the test to not refer back to `self`...

```
brackets = '''d = {}

class AttrDict2(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return d[key]
    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        d[key] = val

o = AttrDict2()
o.att = 1'''

methods = '''d = {}

class AttrDict2(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return d.__getitem__(key)
    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        d.__setitem__(key, val)

o = AttrDict2()
o.att = 1'''
```

Then I again get the behavior that brackets is always faster than methods. So perhaps it has something to do with how `self[]` works in a `dict` subclass?

Comment: Wow, that result with different inheritance was *really* interesting. Thank you for putting so much time into this!